# dart problems with polymer

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I'm trying to make an application in dart and Polymer. 
I have this code:

**app.html**

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/login.css">
    <link rel="import" href="vistas/loginUI.html">

    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Prueba</h1>
    <login-usuario></login-usuario>
      <script type="application/dart"> export 'package:polymer/init.dart';</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**loginUI.html:**

```dart
<polymer-element name="login-usuario">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<template>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/login.css">
  <div id="login">
  <h1><strong>Bienvenido</strong></h1>

  <fieldset>
  <p><input type="text" required id="usuario" name="usuario"
      placeholder="Usuario"></p>
  <p><input type="password" required id="password" name="password"
      placeholder="Contraseña"></p>
  <p><button>ENTRAR</button></p>
  </fieldset>
  </div>
  <p>Hi</p>
</template>
<script type="application/dart" src="loginUI.dart"></script>

</polymer-element>
```

**loginUI.dart**

```dart
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

@CustomTag('login-usuario')
class LoginUI extends PolymerElement{
  @observable String usuario;
  @observable String password;
  @observable bool errorConectar;

  LoginUI.created() : super.created();
}
```

But when I run the application, I can not display anything.
Also, when I create a new polymer proyect (the example) , neither I can not display anything when I run the application.
I added the polymer dependence.

thank you very much!

Comment: Hi, which version of Polymer are you using? Looks like your setup is not correct. You are missing:

@initMethod for main and <link rel="import" href="packages/polymer/polymer.html">

Comment: you are missing <link rel="import" href="packages/polymer/polymer.html"> in loginUI.html

Comment: If I add that line The application still does not work

Comment: where did you put it?

Comment: <polymer-element name="login-usuario">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<template>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/login.css">
 <link rel="import" href="packages/polymer/polymer.html">....

Comment: It has to be before <polymer-element> <meta charset=".."> should be before it as well I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/login.css">

    <!-- <script src="packages/web_components/platform.js"></script>
         not necessary anymore with Polymer >= 0.14.0 -->
    <script src="packages/web_components/dart_support.js"></script>

    <link rel="import" href="vistas/loginUI.html">

    <!--<script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Prueba</h1>
    <login-usuario></login-usuario>

    <script type="application/dart"> export 'package:polymer/init.dart';</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

.

```dart
<!-- how many ../ you need depends on where your element files are stored -->
<link rel="import" href="../../packages/polymer/polymer.html"> 

<polymer-element name="login-usuario">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <template>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/login.css">
    <div id="login">
    <h1><strong>Bienvenido</strong></h1>

    <fieldset>
    <p><input type="text" required id="usuario" name="usuario"
        placeholder="Usuario"></p>
    <p><input type="password" required id="password" name="password"
        placeholder="Contraseña"></p>
    <p><button>ENTRAR</button></p>
    </fieldset>
    </div>
    <p>Hi</p>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="loginUI.dart"></script>

</polymer-element>
```

Your pubspec.yaml should contain

```dart
transformers:
- polymer:
    entry_points:
    - web/app.html
```

Comment: When I do those from modifications, dart give me a exeption: Breaking on exception: ReferenceError: Platform is not defined and reference to polymer.js : d.prototype={valueFn:function(){if(!this..................

Comment: I created a new project using the code above and it worked fine (when I also added the css or removed the css links, see https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=19719)
Which Dart version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Dart Editor version 1.4.0.release (STABLE).
If I run this code,it doesnt work

Comment: I'm using Dart 1.6 bleeding edge. I think you should try 1.5 (stable should be available since a few days).

Comment: I update dart  to 1.5.
Now , when I run the app , dart give me this error: "Failed to create server socket (OS Error: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
, errno = 10013), address = 127.0.0.1, port = 8080"

Comment: Could be http://superuser.com/questions/635498 or check if some other app is already listening on 8080 https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=19076

Comment: Nop. I disabled Avast but dart still giving me the error

Comment: I don't use Windows and I guess I won't be able to help you with this problem. It seems to be more an OS problem than a Dart problem. Either some app is already using this port (I guess you would get another error message in this case) or some service is blocking access to this port (more probable). The reason you start getting this problem with 1.5 is that Dart switched to use `pub serve` instead of DartEditor-integrated web server and maybe because `pub serve` is using port 8080 instead of port 3030 used previously.

Comment: I tried to install dart in ubuntu and run the code... the code is run!
Thanks you very much for your reply and your time!